# How to load Evolutions script (database migration scripts) from external folder or external jar?

Tags: java, playframework-2.2, playframework-evolutions

We are using Play 2.7 (Java) in production. We have a set of common Ebean models (as an external library/jar) that are shared between different Play projects but we are stuck because of Play Evolutions scripts. Is there any way using which these scripts (.sql files) can be loaded from an external folder/jar? Has anybody tried this ever?

Already tried searching for solutions online but no use. Need help from somebody who has good experience with Play. Please also suggest if there is any other way to get around the problem. Thanks for your help in advance!

Currently, the project is running those migration scripts from here:

```
--> project
    --> app
    --> conf
        --> evolutions
            --> default <-- from here
```

I want to load those scripts from somewhere like here:

```
--> project
    --> app
--> External Libraries
    --> group.artifact.version.jar
        --> models
            --> default <-- from here
```